# Jersey client using an authenticated session

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

In a given moment in time an authenticated session is created.

I need to create a jersey client (post method) using that authenticated session.

I've tried set the JSESSIONID in the jersey client but it doesn't recognize the session.

```
    Client client = Client.create();

    final String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/send";

    WebResource wr = client.resource(url);

    javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie cookie=new javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie("JSESSIONID", "521448844J5WE54D");
    wr.cookie(cookie);

    // Set POST parameters
    FormDataMultiPart multipart = new FormDataMultiPart();
    FormDataBodyPart fdp = new FormDataBodyPart("file", uploadedInputStream, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);
    multipart.bodyPart(fdp);

    String response = wr.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(String.class, multipart);

    System.out.println(response);
```

I've tried also the code below, that in the jersey client I call first an API to authenticate the session and then try to use the same client object to call another API that require a auth session, didn't work.

```
    Client client = Client.create();

    final String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/auth";

    WebResource wr = client.resource(url);

     //set parametes for request
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
    queryParams.add("user", "admin");
    queryParams.add("pass", "123456");
    wr.queryParams(queryParams);

    ClientResponse response = wr.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class);

    System.out.println(response.getCookies().toString());

    //------------------------------------------------------------

    final String url2 = "http://localhost:8080/api/send";

    WebResource wr2 = client.resource(url2);

    // Set POST parameters
    FormDataMultiPart multipart = new FormDataMultiPart();

    FormDataBodyPart fdp = new FormDataBodyPart("file", uploadedInputStream, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);
    multipart.bodyPart(fdp);

    String response2 = wr2.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(String.class, multipart);

    System.out.println(response2);
```

How can I do that ? I mean, how to use an authenticated JSESSIONID in a new jersey client connection ?

Regards.

Comment: Register the `LoggingFilter` with the client to see all the headers. You should see the cookie header. Make sure the ids match with the one you send back. You should be able to programmatically send the same one back that is recieved from the initial request by actually extracting it from the cookie map

Comment: You can do `client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());` to register the logging filter

Comment: @peeskillet I did it and I got:  
  
    INFO: 1 * Client in-bound response  
    < 500  
    < Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 17:15:24 GMT  
    < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  
    < Content-Length: 516  
    < Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A414A6D35F8A9CDAECF18D6349B8181  
    < Connection: close  
    < Content-Type: text/html  
    < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true  
   < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1  
  
And it's the same JSESSIONID used in the second API call, but not work.  
  
* Is not the same that in code above. In my real code I'm getting it from response.getCookies();

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do is to use JWT for user Authorization.

I am assuming that you have already authenticated the user via an API Endpoint. Once the user is authenticated, you can reply back a header element. You can read more about JWT @ https://jwt.io/introduction/

Your implementation should look like the following steps.

1) Authenticate the user and upon successful authentication, add "Authorization: " token to the response.

2) In every API call, expect the user to pass the Authorization header with each request and use a [Filter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) to authorize the user by parsing the JWT Token. You may want to @Inject the Parser and make sure that your parser is Threadsafe.

3-a) If the JWT Token is valid, you let the request pass through to your resource.

3-b) If the JWT Token is invalid, you reply back wit HTTP 401.

Here is a sample implementation.

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.BadJOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWT;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTParser;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.ConfigurableJWTProcessor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;


@PreMatching
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@Provider
@Secured
public class SimpleAuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

 static JWTParser jwtParser = null;

 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleAuthorizationFilter.class);

 @Inject
 private ConfigurableJWTProcessor jwtProcessor;

 public SimpleAuthorizationFilter() {
  LOGGER.debug("Init {}", getClass().getName());
 }

 @Override
 public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

  if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
   LOGGER.debug("Began authorization filter for {}", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
  }

  MultivaluedMap < String, String > headers = requestContext.getHeaders();

  JWT jwt = null;

  if (headers.containsKey(AccessTokens.AUTHORIZATION)) {

   String accessToken = headers.getFirst(AccessTokens.AUTHORIZATION);


   try {
    jwt = JWTParser.parse(accessToken);
   } catch (ParseException parseException) {
    LOGGER.error("Unable to parse JWT Token {}, reason {}", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath(), parseException.getMessage());
    throw new WebApplicationException("Unable to parse JWT Token", Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);

   }


   // Check if JWT has been init successfully.
   if (jwt == null) {
    LOGGER.error("JWT is null {}", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
    throw new WebApplicationException("Unable to init JWT", Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
   }


   try {

    if (jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime().before(new java.util.Date())) {
     LOGGER.debug("JWT Token expired on {}, requesting new token ", jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime().toString());

    } else {
     // Do nothing, continue as usual.
    }

   } catch (ParseException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Authorization failed @ {} , due to {}", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath(), e.getMessage());
    throw new WebApplicationException("Unable to Authorize " + e.getMessage(), Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
   }


   SecurityContext ctx = null; // optional context parameter, not required here

   JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = null;


   try {
    claimsSet = jwtProcessor.process(accessToken, ctx);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Authorization failed @ ParseException {} , due to {}", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath(), e.getMessage());
    throw new WebApplicationException("Unable to Authorize " + e.getMessage(), Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
   } catch (BadJOSEException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Authorization failed @ BadJOSEException {} , due to {}", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath(), e.getMessage());
    throw new WebApplicationException("Unable to Authorize " + e.getMessage(), Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
   } catch (JOSEException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Authorization failed @ JOSEException {} , due to {}", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath(), e.getMessage());
    throw new WebApplicationException("Unable to Authorize " + e.getMessage(), Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
   }


   // This should not have happened.
   if (claimsSet == null) {
    LOGGER.error("JWT Claim is null failed @ {} , due to {}", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
    throw new WebApplicationException("Unable to Authorize", Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
   }

  } else {
   LOGGER.error("Authorization header is missing {}", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
   throw new WebApplicationException("Authorization header is missing", Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
  }


 }

}
```

I actually created an annotation `@Secured` and any resource method annotated with `@Secured` will be greeted first with this filter.

Here is my Annotation:

```
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Secured { }
```

Then I created a DynamicFeature as:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.container.DynamicFeature;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class ResourceFilterBindingFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceFilterBindingFeature.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        if (resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().isAnnotationPresent(Secured.class)) {
            LOGGER.info("{} is annotated to be a secure method " , resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getName() );
            context.register(CustomAuthorizationFilter.class);
        }

    }
}
```

You will need to register the above DyamicFeature in Jersey as

```
register(SimpleAuthorizationFilter.class)
```

Finally, here is my resource that I used to test

```
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/authorizationTest")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class AuthorizationTest {

    @GET
    @Path("/secure")
    @Secured
    public Response secure(){

        return Response.ok(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/unsecure")
    public Response unsecure(){
        return Response.ok(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

    }

}
```

Hope that helps.